# Getting some sort of border when positioning a div below an image?

Tags: html, css, border, positioning

So I have an image with 100% width , and I have a div that I want to position directly below that image.
There seems to be some sort of border or line between the image and the div that I can't seem to get rid of, which I know is from the background I'm not in the mood to use fixed position because then it wouldn't be directly below it on various resolutions.
I've tried resetting body padding and margin to 0 but it doesn't seem to help.

HTML:

```
    <header>

        <img class="forumheader" src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/50356_434008550256_1008261_n.jpg"/>

    </header>

    <div class="content">
        I am a content.
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.content{
height:400px;
width:100%;
background: #202020;
}

body{
background:#ff00ff;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AYnaN/
The image doesn't have 100% width in that jsfiddle because of the size but the image in my application has 100% width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image has style `display:inline-block;` or `display:inline;` by default in most browsers. So it's treated as text and browser is displaying this additional line to separate text lines.

Try giving the image: `style="display:block;"`.
Also remember to set margins to 0: `style="margin:0px;"`.

Here is your modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AYnaN/1/.